# Why wont it loop? (PHP and MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I wrote this code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("internal");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Title, Message FROM msg");
?>

<?php

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
?>

     <div>
         <h3><a href="#"><?php printf("%s", $row[0]); ?></a></h3>
         <div><?php printf("%s", $row[1]); ?></div>
     </div>

<?php
 mysql_free_result($result);
  }
?>
```

The result I´m getting is the first row of the MySQL table (With the correct formatting) I include an Image just in case:

[image: screeshot result]

(This is in fact the first row of my MySQL DB and the only thing I see)

The code was looping until I had to add the html tags, what I mean is that if I just do:

```
<?php printf("%s", $row[0]); ?>
&
<?php printf("%s", $row[1]); ?>
```

It looped and brought all of the results.

Could this be a syntax error?

Comment: Thanks to all! The problem is definitely solved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysql_free_result($result);` inside your while loop. This makes it so after the first iteration, it clears the results, making so no more can be grabbed.

Change your ending to

```
<?php
  }
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

and it'll fix it

Answer (score 2):

Your third-to-last line frees the result before you're done with it. Move it outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

move the call to  mysql_free_result to be outside of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are freeing result after the first loop. Here

```
mysql_free_result($result);
 }
```

This should be

```
  }
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't mysql_free_result clear the result set?

You have nothing left to loop over!